# How to call Tether.to API in Angular.js using CryptoJS

Tags: angularjs, cryptojs

I'm developing an app in Angularjs which calls some APIs of the Tether.to site (http://platform.tether.to/).

The API requires to send header following this form:

```
Authorization: APIAuth TetherAPIKey:Signature
```

The Authorization header is computed as following:

```
Authorization = “APIAuth” + “ ” + TetherAPIKey + “:” + Signature;
Signature = Base64( HMAC-SHA1( TetherAPISecret, StringToSign ) );
StringToSign = Content-Type + “,” + Content-MD5 + “,” + URI + “,” + Timestamp;
```

I implemented using below code in AngularJS:

```
var url, timestamp, stringToSign, signature, request, r,
    apiKey = 'xxxxxxx', apiSecret = 'xxxxxxxPo95gm9eoCeFyTTw3zeCFf';
url = 'https://wallet.tether.to/api/v1/transactions';
timestamp = new Date().toUTCString();
stringToSign = 'application/json,' + CryptoJS.MD5('') + ',' + url + ',' + timestamp;
signature = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(stringToSign, apiSecret));
request = {
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'APIAuth ' + apiKey + ':' + signature }
};
r = $http.get(url, request).success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Where's the wrong in my code? Why does the API ("/transactions") always return `{"code":401,"error":"Unauthorized"}`?

Answer (score 0):

CryptoJS encodes by default to Hex when you force the WordArray to be converted to string, but `Content-MD5` must be Base 64 encoded (judging from the ruby code of the project).

Try:

```
stringToSign = 'application/json,' + CryptoJS.MD5('').toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64) + ',' + url + ',' + timestamp;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your suggestion but it still gets error 401 when request to the api.

Comment: I don't know. Try to switch the arguments of `CryptoJS.HmacSHA1`.